# How to use string to string hash_map(hash_map<string, string, stringHashFunction> in Linux C++

Tags: c++, gcc

I define a hash_map<string, string, stringHashFunction> stringHashMap in Ubuntu with GCC. And I promise that stringHashFunction is right, because I can use string to in hash_map correctly

When I call

```
string a = "sgsg";
string temp = stringHash[a];
```

the compiler report bugs that:

> error: passing ‘const __gnu_cxx::hash_map, std::basic_string, StringHashFunctionStruct>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘_Tp& __gnu_cxx::hash_map<_Key, _Tp, _HashFn, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string, _Tp = std::basic_string, _HashFn = StringHashFunctionStruct, _EqualKey = std::equal_to >, _Alloc = std::allocator >, __gnu_cxx::hash_map<_Key, _Tp, _HashFn, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Why could this happen? How should I use string to string hashMap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` accessor can modify the map, hence it can't be non-const.  use find instead

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/

> Notice how the last access (to element 'd') inserts a new element in
>   the map with that key and initialized to its default value (an empty
>   string) even though it is accessed only to retrieve its value. Member
>   function map::find does not produce this effect.

Answer (score 3):

`stringHash` is either directly `const` or passed/stored as a const reference. The `operator[]` is a non-const function because it may need to insert an item. If you need to find an item in a const hash container, just use the `find` method.